# Is possible set table or \textwidth fixed width in cm? (LATEX)

Tags: pdftex

I need create a table in a document with a width of exactly 24cm. Print will be A4 - landscape (in EU if it matters). Is there some way set it?

If I set:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,top=0cm, bottom=0cm, left=0cm, right=0cm]{geometry}
```

then my `\textwidth` is 29.69577cm.

EDIT (I forgot):

when I set:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,textwidth=24cm]{geometry}
```

then my `\textwidth` is 23.99658cm

I want to use this later on:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}
```

I am doing somethig wrong?

Comment: Should the table or the text block have width `240cm` exactly? Also, `margin=0cm` is equivalent to `top=0cm, bottom=0cm, left=0cm, right=0cm`.

Comment: It isn't 240cm but 24cm - sorry my bad. It is ok now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,top=0cm, bottom=0cm, left=0cm, right=0cm]{geometry}
\typeout{* paper width: \the\paperwidth}
\typeout{* text width: \the\textwidth}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The margins are zero, thus the text width equals the paper width:

```
* paper width: 845.04684pt
* text width: 845.04684pt
```

Conversion to cm:

```
* 72.27 pt = 1 in
* 1 in = 2.54 cm
```

Result (gcalculator): 29.6999996347 cm
Result (perl<sup>1</sup>): 29.6999996347032 cm

This is pretty close to the `29.7 cm` of the longer side of A4 paper.

TeX's accuracy is limited by it smallest unit: 1 sp

- 1 pt = 2<sup>16</sup> sp = 65536 sp ≈ 0.000000536285 cm

Specifying 297 mm instead of 29.7 cm improves the accuracy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, paperheight=297mm, landscape, margin=0cm]{geometry}
\typeout{* paper width: \the\paperwidth}
\typeout{* text width: \the\textwidth}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
* paper width: 845.04684pt
* text width: 845.04684pt
```

Conversion to cm (perl): 29.6999996347032 cm

(By adding 1 sp this can be made larger and a tiny little bit closer to 29.7 cm.)

### Second case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,textwidth=24cm]{geometry}

\typeout{* text width: \the\textwidth}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
* text width: 682.86613pt
```

Conversion to cm (perl): 23.9999995876574 cm

Again very close to 24 cm, the greatest value ≤ 24 cm in TeX.
(It could made be closer to, but larger as 24 cm by adding 1 sp.)

### Calculations in TeX

A scaling operation (multiplication followed by division) in e-TeX's `\...expr` commands provide the best accuracy, from the e-TeX [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/e-tex/v2/doc/etex_man.pdf):

> The arithmetic operations are performed individually, except for
>   'scaling' operations (a multiplication immediately followed by a
>   division) which are performed as one combined operation with a 64-bit
>   product as intermediate value.

Also e-TeX's `\...expr` commands round the result rather than truncate it to fit the result in TeX's internal sp scala.

Second case as example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,textwidth=240mm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\typeout{* text width: \strip@pt\dimexpr\textwidth*254/7227\relax cm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The real numbers 2.54 and 72.27 are multiplied by 100 to get an integer for the divisor. `\strip@pt` removes the `pt` at the end. Result:

```
* text width: 24cm
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `perl -e 'print 845.04684/72.27*2.54'`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a setup that could work for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  paper=a4paper, % A4 paper = 210mm x 297mm
  landscape, % 297mm x 210mm in landscape mode
  hmargin=28.5mm, % horizontal margin = 2 x 28.5mm = 57mm
                  %  > text width = 297mm - 57mm = 240mm = 24cm
  vmargin=10mm}   % vertical margin = 2 x 10mm = 20mm
                  %  > text height = 210mm - 20mm = 190mm = 19cm
\usepackage{printlen}
\uselengthunit{cm}
\begin{document}
\verb|\textwidth|:  \printlength\textwidth\par
\verb|\textheight|: \printlength\textheight
\end{document}
```

The above outputs

```
\textwidth: 23.99658cm
\textheight: 18.9973cm
```

which is close enough to a 24cm text width. The (negligble) difference is due to rounding.

If you're interested in a table having some fixed width, consider using a [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) with flexible `X`-columns.

Comment: THX for a clarification. One more question -> Is difference between setting hmargin+vmargin or only textwidth?

Comment: @LajdákMarek: Not really, as long as you remember that hmargin+textwidth=paperwidth (hmargin=left+right) and vmargin+textheight=paperheight (vmargin=top+bottom).